# Multicontrol SDN architecture

Tags: load-balancing, multiple-instances, sdn, pox

How can I make two pox controllers communicate to transfer the load within them?

I could invoke two pox controller but switch just communicating with one controller?

Comment: Please read first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then if you can refine your question.

Comment: I am initiating multiple pox controller instances. I want to distribute the load between 2 pox controllers. I want to check the load on 2 controllers compare and distribute the load. Very simple application. How can I do that

Comment: [please refer this question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728900/multicontrol-sdn-architecture).its a similar question

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link...it a similar question [Communicating between multiple pox controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384775/communicating-between-multiple-pox-controllers)
sorry there was a mistake in comment.... i am not able to edit it